# Laravel form inputs missing from request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the following form:

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.blocks.store', [$page->id]) }}" method="post">
    <fieldset>

        <div>
            <input id="block--page-id" name="page_id" type="text" disabled value="{{ $page->id }}">
            <lable for="block--page-id">Page ID</lable>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input id="block--name" name="name" type="text">
            <label for="block--name">Name</label>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input id="block--description" name="description" type="text">
            <label for="block--description">Description</label>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input id="block--key" name="key" type="text">
            <label for="block--key">Key</label>
        </div>

        <div>
            <textarea id="block--value" name="value">
            </textarea>
            <label for="block--value">Value</label>
        </div>

        <div>
            <button type="submit">Create</button>
        </div>

        {{ csrf_field()}}
    </fieldset>
```

With the following controller:

```
public function blocksStore(Request $request, $pageId)
{
    $block = new PageBlock();

    $block->page_id = $request->input('page_id');
    $block->name = $request->input('name');
    $block->description = $request->input('description');
    $block->key = $request->input('key');
    $block->value = $request->input('value');

    $block->save();
    return redirect('admin.pages.edit', [$pageId]);
}
```

However, my input for `page_id` doesn't get passed into the request. All the other inputs work fine so I'm unsure of what else could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the element is `disabled`, it will not be submitted. So, change it to `type="hidden"`:

```
<input id="block--page-id" name="page_id" type="hidden" value="{{ $page->id }}">
```

Comment: Is there a way I can still show it on the page as disabled but still submit? I wanted to be able to see the id I'm using. I guess i could just have another field which is hidden and one which is disabled and access the disabled one in the request?

Comment: @SamWillis you could try [readonly](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp) or just display the number near the element.

Answer (score 1):

Change your form action to :

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.blocks.store', ['page_id'=> $page->id]) }}" method="post">
```

It assumes your route definition is :

```
Route::post('/your_url/{page_id}', 'SomeController@store')->name('admin.blocks.store');
```

And in your controller code, you don't need to get `$pageId` from request as it is already there as a route parameter.

```
public function blocksStore(Request $request, $pageId)
{
$block = new PageBlock();

$block->page_id = $pageId;

$block->save();
return redirect('admin.pages.edit', [$pageId]);
}
```